# What are the cause that i have to shift 2 times when shifting from the smallest chainring to the big one?

Tags: road-bike, shifting

When i try to change gear 1 time from the smallest chainring to largest one, it wont move and it will make a sound and the chain will fall off if i didnt click to chage gear again. Until i do it 2 times, it can move to the biggest chainring. What are the possible causes and what adjustment do i need to make?

Comment: Just a tip, but your use of “biggest” and “smallest” makes it sound like you have 3 or more chainrings to me. If you say “big” and “small” then it’ll be clear you have exactly 2.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have two chainrings? Most road bike shifters have a third “trim” position for the front derailleur. It moves the derailleur towards the middle and is not intended to actually shift the chain. When you ride the big-big or small-small chainring/sprocket combinations the chain can rub on the front derailleur. The trim position is there to avoid this. You are only supposed to use it in those combinations. Otherwise, if you want to shift front gears, just firmly press the lever all the way and it should shift nicely.

The trim position feels slightly different from normal shifting. It doesn’t *click* and engage as firmly. If it feels like a normal shift position, maybe you have a shifter which is actually intended for triple chainrings?

Comment: I only have 2 chainrings. So i should push the left lever all the way to move it to the large chainring? I sometimes fear of pushing the lever for the FD cuz the chain might slip off. No problems when shifting from big to small and i rarely touched the front gears

Comment: Yes, you should push the lever all the way. If you can overshift so that the chain drops, you should adjust the limit screws on the front derailleur to stop it.